# Flutter Flame game - animation speed (update duration)

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, flame

for those who are familiar with using Flame in Flutter for game development, I'm wondering if you can just advise me whether I'm on the right track, or not - because I'm not sure if what I'm seeing in my testing is what I expected.  I started out with Flame because I thought it seemed like a relatively simple way to make the basic game that I'm aiming to make.

I'm making a basic game where there are four boundaries defined on each edge of the screen, and a ball will bounce around the four boundaries.  The boundaries are defined as widgets (because I want to control the properties of each - sometimes they'll be "electrified", meaning the ball shouldn't collide with them).  And the ball is a widget as well, of course.  I've got some basic code done where I can drag a line from the ball to indicate the direction that I want to start bouncing, and then the ball will bounce around the boundaries (just using basic angle of incidence = angle of reflection to determine the direction of movement).

The code to do the movement is in the "update" method of the ball widget - however, what I'm finding is that the time between updates is somewhere around 200-300 milliseconds, so if I want to show the ball moving at any kind of pace, it has to jump a good number of pixels at each "update" tick - and thus the movement looks "jerky".

Am I doing this the right way?  Is there a different (better) approach that will make the movement appear smoother?  Or, I'm wondering whether the duration of the "update" ticks is a result of running the code via debug in an Android emulator?  (I'm using Android Studio for the emulation, and Visual Studio Code to build the project).  I know I don't have actual code here in the question, because essentially I don't have an issue with my code not running - I would just like to understand if that duration of "update" ticks is "normal", and if the resulting "jerky" animation is just to be expected - or do I need to look at a different approach?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should preferably not be using widgets for moving game parts, you should be using Flame components. So you could have for example 4 `SpriteComponent`s as the walls and then the ball as another `SpriteComponent` and then you can use the collision detection system to act upon when the ball touches one of the walls.

https://docs.flame-engine.org/main/collision_detection.html